# SO Jobs recommends positions related to your ignored tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Until recently, I had only 3 favorite tags and no ignored tags. SO Jobs was recommending relevant positions based on my favorites.

A few days ago I added a load of tags to my ignored tags section of the homepage, and now I am getting loads of jobs come up relating to my ignored tags.

This is a bug and should be fixed.

A screenshot of some of my ignored tags, and then some job offers, is below.

Is anyone else having the same problem?

[image: The screenshot I mentioned]

Comment: dunno... that could have some unwanted side effects. For example, someone may ignore a particular framework tag because that tag on SO is full of garbage questions, but wouldn't mind seeing job offerings that happen to have that tag.

Comment: @KevinB so maybe there should be a section that allows you to select which tags show for jobs, by default none

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug; it's by design. Ignored tags are related to the Q&A part of the site and have nothing to do with jobs or ads related to jobs. If you want to change the behaviour of jobs you need to edit your job preferences either by using the [image: match preferences] button in the matches tab or by modifying your [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) in your profile.